What happens between travelling and rest?
Rules of exploration mode of Pathfinder 2e had recently puzzled me.

Here is said that every 24 hours characters need 8 hours of rest and if they'd go for more than 16 hours without it - they'd be fatigued.
Here is table of distances that characters can cover - and it's clear from that table is that per day characters are supposed to spend only 8 hours walking.

Is there any explanation about what happens during the other 8 hours before rest? Are there some mandatory activities that take those 8 hours? Is there limit on time of activity characters can do during day? Like - if characters spent 8 hours to reach some ruins - can they start exploring them? Because, according to rules of travel - they are too tired to walk anywhere by that time.
Thanks everyone for answering about what CAN be done during that time, it is going to help me set up some camp activities for player for sure.
But, I want to clarify that question is about what characters MUST do, according to rules. Is there anything that must take part of 16 hour-day that characters have, something that is written in official rules (or other official sources) that takes their time. Supposedly taking 8 hours that they are supposed to stay awake, but not travelling and whether it can be combined with some other activities (like exploring dungeons) or not. Alternatively - I'm looking for explanation (also official) - why travelling speed table lists travel distance per day as if characters have travelled only 8 hours per day.
Right now I'm aware that 1 hour per day is taken by daily preparations and unlike some other RPGs, daily preparations are not part of the rest.
And that after 8 hours of travelling in fine weather characters are supposed to get fatigued (though fatigue shouldn't stop them from travelling, just limit exploration activities and impose AC penalty, but still in may be the reason for that travelling speed table to list only 8 hours of travel per day).

Why is the assumption that those open-ended hours aren't those spent in the dungeon or carousing the streets?

@Jason_c_o - well, that's exactly the question. 'Travel speed' table suggets that characters can travel only distance equal to 8-hours of their speed per day. If they can't walk down the road any further - why they should be able to walk inside the dungeon? And if they can walk in the dungeon - why can't they continue walking on the road?

They can, as long as they get 8 hours of rest...

Why would this not be accounted for by all the things you have to do to survive that don’t fall under sleeping? The rules for rest all but say that you need to be sleeping (or equivalent) for that time (which lines up with reality), so time spent hunting, foraging, pitching and tearing down camp, preparing meals, maintaining gear, practicing skills, and similar is part of this. You could track all of that if you wanted, but then nobody would want to play with you because it’s boring minutiae that doesn’t have a mechanical impact beyond whether or not it happens (just like sleeping).

@AustinHemmelgarn - because pathfinder 2e is highly mechanical-based game, with rules for everything, even for striking conversations with NPC and asking for their help. And also, setting up the camp, maintaining gear, etc, sound as very optional activities that shouldn't be enforced. Imagine party travelling between two towns - distance is 24 miles. Can they march for some extra hours and reach the town? If not - what stops them? Imagine same party that spent 4 hours marching to some ruins and spent 4 hours exploring them - can they head back? Or do they have something they must do?

The other 8 hours is raising and striking camp and taking care of gear.
It takes a lot of time to build a shelter, collect firewood, prepare a meal, and so on in a world without gas stoves and high-tech tents. Additionally, your dinner might need to be trapped or foraged first.
You need time to look after your gear. Leather needs to be cleaned and conditioned, metal must be cleaned and oiled, weapons have to be sharpened.
Time is required to look after your skills. Warriors will be exercising and doing drills, bards will be practicing songs and poems, wizards will be studying their books, and so on.
Social and spiritual activities both take time as well.


I'm looking more for explanation from a rulebook, preferably with a link to the rule, so I'd be able to tell players - why after eight hours of travel they still have eight hours before they can go to bed, but they can't dive into ruins.
But what if characters are travelling between cities? Does it really take eight hours to find a new tavern and order a meal there?
And I'm more and more curious about what would happen to characters if they'd march (or do something) not for 8, but for 9 hours. In PF1 there were rules for such things, but in PF2 - there is void at that place.


@Sarge: Everything this answer lists is something you'd do day-to-day, but that you can skip if needs must and there's a dungeon that needs to be explored immediately. My concern here isn't the lack of justification (this answer provides it), it's the underlying granularity that you're trying to introduce in the game by effectively tracking people's activities on a timesheet. 8 hours walking for travel speed is a reasonable average expectation for an average day. This omits details, e.g. terrain difficulties, weather, minor illness, getting lost, having a nice lunch and chat, ...

@Sarge: If you want to go more granular into this, then have at it. But be very aware that increased realism doesn't always mean increased fun.

After some research and digging through the rules - I found what limits travelling per day. There is an obscure table of temperature effects in GM Core, that states that during a fine weather overland travel is limited to 8 hours before characters would get fatigued. Less if weather is colder or warmer.
There are no obligatory activities that characters should take during the day, aside from daily preparations that take about an hour. Walking in some dungeon doesn't count as travelling (despite of some dungeons being really big), so there you can spend all 16 hours walking.
Setting up camp, cooking food, training and other things are not mandatory activities and are not listed in basic rules, only in some additional supplements (like Kingmaker adventure path)

Excellent spot. This leads to the conclusion that a party can probably travel more than 8 hours in a day, but they'll be fatigued for that second half.

Most of the remaining time would be spent dealing with daily chores.
1) Setting up camp.
You would want to make sure your camp is set up in such a way to insulate you from as much of the hazards of the local environment as possible.
2) Finding and boiling water.
This would be a daily occurrence, and a major priority, unless the party has a magic source of water. Drinking water you find in nature can have significant risks, whether it be contamination from an animal carcass that you didn't know is upstream or other potential disease vectors. the average human can survive for only about 3ish days without water, but significantly longer without food.
3) Hunting/trapping food.
You want to eat fresh food as often as possible, since it lasts less time than the rations that are specifically prepared for longer-term storage. Eating fresh food also allows you to preserve the travel rations you are carrying for the days when you can't find anything safe to eat at all.
4) Repairing gear from daily wear.
Anything that gets daily use would need to be checked to make sure it's not showing signs of damage, and be repaired if it was starting to show sign of damage. Boots/shoes would be checked for wear in the sole and upper, straps for backpacks, saddlebags (if mounted), and saddles for mounts would be inspected for wear, harnesses for beast of burden pulling carts would need inspection, the list of gear needing inspection is essentially the same as the list of anything that was used that day in any capacity.
5) Stretching out muscles.
Most modern-day backpackers will spend some time at the end of the hiking day stretching their legs, and rolling the muscles in their legs on something round, so that they can keep traveling the same distance every day. If you fail to stretch out muscles, you can cramp up during the night, and you won't be able to travel as far, if at all, the next day.
6) Keeping in practice with class skills.
This varies depending on the class, but all classes would have things they need to do to keep combat-ready. A cleric might spend some of the time praying to their god and preparing their spells for the next day, while a fighter would be practicing with their weapons.
7) Tending to any injuries/illnesses.
This could include having to find medicinal herbs in the local area to help stop bleeding or settle an upset stomach, cleansing an wound, checking on a older wound to make sure it's healing well, and many other things like that. Never discount how much even a simple blister can make a difference to an adventurer's ability to travel, and how valuable making sure it heals is.
Most of this can be found in far more detail by looking for backpacker, bushcraft, and reenactor videos on YouTube.
